# CherryPy ssl certificate

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have a small application written on top of cherrypy. I'd like to run it under the default cherrypy server. I have my domain + my ssl verified certificate by Comodo. I've been trying to get it running under a simple app for the past 24 hours without any luck. I've written a test application which looks like this:

```
import cherrypy

class RootServer:
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self, **keywords):
        return "SSL HERE WE COME!!!!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_config={
        'server.socket_host': 'mydomain.com',
        'server.socket_port':443,

        'server.ssl_module':'pyopenssl',
        'server.ssl_certificate':'/var/www/certs/mydomain_com.crt',
        'server.ssl_private_key':'/var/www/certs/mydomain.com.key',
        'server.ssl_certificate_chain':'/var/www/certs/bundle.pem'
    }

    cherrypy.config.update(server_config)
    cherrypy.quickstart(RootServer())
```

It fires up without giving any problems. However when I try to access it I get the following:

```
alex@asus:~> openssl s_client -connect mydomain.com:443 -state -nbio 2>&1 | grep "^SSL"
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
SSL3 alert read:fatal:handshake failure
SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 261 bytes
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to figure it out but I got it running. Leaving a comment here in case someone hits the same rock:

```
import cherrypy

class RootServer:
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self, **keywords):
        return 'Success!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_config={
        'server.socket_host': 'mydomain.com',
        'server.socket_port':443,

        'server.ssl_module':'pyopenssl',
        'server.ssl_certificate':'/home/axe/CERTS/domain.crt',
        'server.ssl_private_key':'/home/axe/CERTS/myserver.key',
    }

    cherrypy.config.update(server_config)
    cherrypy.quickstart(RootServer())
```